# Storing/retrieving a JSON string in the database making it easy to work with in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json, json.net

I have a c# object 'Product' with a property called: Offset
In the database the field is of type nvarchar(50)

I will be storing a JSON value in it such as the following: { "y": 0, "m": 0, "d": 0 }

I would like to know a good way of working with a property like this in my code. Here is how I currently am doing it:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    public int OffsetYears { get; set; }
    public int OffsetMonths { get; set; }
    public int OffsetDays { get; set; }

    public string Offset
    {
        get
        {
            Offset offset = new Offset()
            {
                Y = OffsetYears,
                M = OffsetMonths,
                D = OffsetDays
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(offset);
        }
        set
        {
            OffsetObj offset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Offset>(value);

            OffsetYears = offset.Y;
            OffsetMonths = offset.M;
            OffsetDays = offset.D;
        }
    }

    private class OffsetObj
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int M { get; set; }
        public int D { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

So then when I accept values from the User in the UI I would set the OffsetYears, OffsetMonths, and OffsetDays properties.. So in my repository I can just save Offset.

And when retrieving values from the database I will simply work with OffsetYears, OffsetMonths, and OffsetDays properties in my code.

Is there a better way to handle this sort of thing? I just feel like I am not utilizing all of my c# resources. Like what if another developer accidentally sets Offset through the code assuming any format of string can go in it.

Or am I better off just creating 3 separate integer fields in the database and avoiding all of this...

Comment: I think you mean to return serialized OffsetObj from the Offset property instead. And yes, you are right, to reduce ambiguity and normalize your data (if not using no-sql), consider converting the JSON into a C# obj into respective database attributes of the respective entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would hold the values in a field of your private type. Consider this approach:

```
public class Product
{
    private OffsetObj _offset = new OffsetObj();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int OffsetYears
    {
        get { return _offset.Y; }
        set { _offset.Y = value; }
    }

    public int OffsetMonths
    {
        get { return _offset.M; }
        set { _offset.M = value; }
    }

    public int OffsetDays
    {
        get { return _offset.D; }
        set { _offset.D = value; }
    }

    public string Offset
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_offset);
        }
        set
        {
            _offset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OffsetObj>(value);
        }
    }

    private class OffsetObj
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int M { get; set; }
        public int D { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This way, the field *offset* will hold the values for the offset.

> Like what if another developer accidentally sets Offset through the code assuming any format of string can go in it.

JsonConvert will throw a *JsonReaderException* if trying to set the Offset property to a string that does not match JSON-format. In my opinion this is expected. To clarify further, you could name your property to *OffsetJson*.

However, I fail to see the benefit in this simple case to store your information as JSON. If you are using a relational database, you may as well just store your values in separate columns.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Perfect! Is it fine to create a private class inside of my Product class? Does this make sense? I have one other object that will need a similar object.

Comment: That depends. As long as Product is the only class that uses it. You may as well keep it as a private class inside Product to avoid cluttering the namespace. If it makes sense to your domain with an _Offset_ type, make it global.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. I agree, I am about to just split it out into 3 fields.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but something seems off. When this product object is set from a database select is it going to work? for example Select Offset FROM Product

Comment: Is Offset still a string? In that case, yes. When you select the _Offset_ column value you will have to set the _Offset_ property on your created product. Maybe you need to show your database interaction code?